# Trello API isnt calling the success handler?

Tags: javascript, trello

I have an issue where we have the Trello API adding a new card to a defined list, and it is successfully adding to the list, however we are trying to use the .done to close the current window and open a hard-coded trello board. This code is used to take a record from CRM and copy the code to Trello.

```
    var creatingtheCard = function () {
        var record = getRecord(getParameterByName("id"))

        if (record.Description == null) {
            record.Description = "";
        }

        var options = document.getElementById("ListNameItem");
        var listId = options[options.selectedIndex].value

        Trello.post("cards", { name: record.Title, desc: record.Description + " - " + record.CustomerId.Name, idList: listId})
         .done(closeWinOpenTrello)
         .error(failure);
    }

    function closeWinOpenTrello() {
        window.open("http://trello.com/b/8QWBDiTI")
        window.close()
    }
```

This function is called and it successfully creates the new card in Trello, but it wont perform the closeWinOpenTrello function, but it will perform the .error.

Also i ran this in the debugger and when i run the code step by step it will give the error and then close the window and open a new window with Trello.

Thanks in advance

**Update 1**

This is the failure function

```
    var failure = function (error) {
        alert(error.statusText);
    }
```

Comment: What's the response given (status code and body)?  Also, the Trello api just returns the object returned by `$.ajax`, and `.error` is deprecated - you should use `.fail` instead.

Comment: The only thing i got was an error message that read "error" and thats all, i also changed it to .fail as suggested, but no difference in result.

Comment: This is presumably a cross-domain request, which means that you can't get the actual error from JavaScript.  You'll need to inspect the request in another way - the "Network" tab in the Chrome Dev Tools panel would work.

Comment: Right i used the "Network" tab and when the error pops up the "api.trello/1/cards" is claiming to have cancelled, however when click 'ok' on the error it continues and there's no issues.. As i said it still creates the card but it still gives the error.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something external to the code shown here that's causing it to be cancelled (that's what that state typically means).  How is that function being called?

Comment: Its being called from a submit button on a form.

Comment: I should also mention that the error only appears in google chrome, when in IE the html page refreshes and losing the record data, but it still doesn't open the new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cancel the form submission.  Otherwise the page changing will cause the `cancelled` state of the request - the browser isn't going to bother waiting for the response after the page changes, because there's no longer anything waiting on the response.

In order to do this, just return `false` from the `onsubmit` handler.